# List of Tuples remove error

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

ExpenseL is my list of tuples and I try to remove from the list starting from **start** to **stop** but I just get this error: **in removeFromAtoB
    expenseL.pop(i)
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**
Please help me!!! :)

```
def removeFromAtoB():
    aux = copy.deepcopy(expenseL)
    print(expenseL, "\n")
    start = int(input("Starting point: "))
    stop = int(input("Ending point: "))
    j = 0
    for i in expenseL:
        if j >= start and j <= stop:
            expenseL.pop(i)
        j += 1
    print(expenseL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating over your list of tuples:

```
for i in expenseL
```

That means `i` will be one of those tuples. Then you try to use it in `list.pop`:

```
expenseL.pop(i)
```

This won't work, because `list.pop` expects an index. Just enumerate your list:

```
for index, tpl in enumerate(expenseL):
    ...
    expenseL.pop(index)
```

But this breaks, too, because the indices change when you remove an element. You could circumvent that by *not* increasing `j` in that case, but the simpler way is just assigning an empty list to the slice:

```
def removeFromAtoB():
    start = int(input("Starting point: "))
    stop = int(input("Ending point: "))
    expenseL[start:stop+1] = []
```